# Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content Capybara no comprueba contenido de pagina

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, capybara

Hola he creado mi prueba con capybara y rspec.
Este es mi test

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.feature "Users", type: :feature do
  context "crear nuevo usuario" do
    scenario "creacion exitosa" do
      user= FactoryBot.create(:user, :super_usuario)
      login_as(user, :scope => :user)
      visit new_user_path
      within('#frm_user') do 
       fill_in('user_user', with: 'elusuario')
       fill_in('user_name', with: 'Jhon Smith')
       fill_in('user_email', with: 'jsmith@hotmail.com')
       select('Cliente', from: 'user[roles]')
       fill_in('user_password', with: '123456')
      end
      click_button 'Grabar'
      expect(page).to have_content('Usuario creado satisfactoriamente.')  
    end  
  end

  context "editar usuario" do 
  end

  context "eliminar usuario" do 
  end  
end
```

Y este es el metodo en mi controlador

```
 POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @flag_nuevo_usuario=true
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    authorize @user

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'Usuario creado satisfactoriamente.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Pero cuando ejecuto solo me arroja un error que falla , mas no me dice que valor esta devolviendo. Estoy usando pundit con devise y para validar el acceso a pruebas he configurado en mi rails_helper.rb

```
#Para que se pueda autenticar por capybara para pruebas
 config.include Warden::Test::Helpers
```

Esta es la traza de error:

```
Users crear nuevo usuario creacion exitosa
 Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content('Usuario creado satisfactoriamente.')
   expected to find text "Usuario creado satisfactoriamente." in "Dashboard Charts Tables Dato Maestros Navbar Cards Example Pages Login Page Registration Page Forgot Password Page Blank Page Reportes Second Level Item Second Level Item Second Level Item Third Level Third Level Item Third Level Item Third Level Item Messages 12 New New Messages: David Miller 11:21 AM Hey there! This new version of SB Admin is pretty awesome! These messages clip off when they reach the end of the box so they don't overflow over to the sides! Jane Smith 11:21 AM I was wondering if you could meet for an appointment at 3:00 instead of 4:00. Thanks! John Doe 11:21 AM I've sent the final files over to you for review. When you're able to sign off of them let me know and we can discuss distribution. View all messages Alerts 6 New New Alerts: Status Update 11:21 AM This is an automated server response message. All systems are online. Status Update 11:21 AM This is an automated server response message. All systems are online. Status Update 11:21 AM This is an automated server response message. All systems are online. View all alerts Logout Inicio/users NUEVO USUARIO /users 1 error impiden que se pueda guardar el registro: User has already been taken × User Name Email Roles Supervisor Contador Cliente Gerente general Gerente operaciones Password Grabar Atras Copyright © Orsis 2018 Ready to Leave? × Select \"Logout\" below if you are ready to end your current session. Cancel Logout"
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error que te muestra?

Comment: Hola Gerry, he añadido la traza de error a mi pregunta

Comment: Parece que no se ha podido generar el usuario correctamente, posiblemente alguna validación esté causando el error. ¿Qué pasa si creas ese mismo usuario, con los mismos atributos, desde la consola?

Comment: Ahora me arroja otro error lo que hice fue poner el boton fuera de el bloque within . me arroja el error "User has already been taken"

Comment: ¿Estás limpiando la BD de prueba antes de cada ejecución? Por ejemplo utilizando _database cleaner_.

Comment: Si, he utlizado Database Cleaner.rb. El problema era que estaba creando un usuario con el mismo nombre de usuario en mi factory. Ya lo solucione voy a colocar la respuesta. Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Súper; no olvides también aceptar tu respuesta. Suerte!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tuve que corregir varios cosas:

1) El click_button de capybara estaba dentro de el bloque within("#frm_user") . Lo saque y lo puse asi:

```
      within('#frm_user') do 
       fill_in('user_user', with: 'elusuario')
       fill_in('user_name', with: 'Jhon Smith')
       fill_in('user_email', with: 'jsmith@hotmail.com')
       select('Cliente', from: 'user[roles]')
       fill_in('user_password', with: '123456')
      end
      click_button 'Grabar'
      expect(page).to have_content('Jhon Smith')
```

2)dentro de la carpeta spec/support/ ..cree el archivo database_cleaner.rb
 y coloque lo siguiente.

```
require 'capybara/rspec'

#...

RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  config.before(:suite) do
    if config.use_transactional_fixtures?
      raise(<<-MSG)
        Delete line `config.use_transactional_fixtures = true` from rails_helper.rb
        (or set it to false) to prevent uncommitted transactions being used in
        JavaScript-dependent specs.

        During testing, the app-under-test that the browser driver connects to
        uses a different database connection to the database connection used by
        the spec. The app's database connection would not be able to access
        uncommitted transaction data setup over the spec's database connection.
      MSG
    end
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end



  config.before(:each, type: :feature) do
    # :rack_test driver's Rack app under test shares database connection
    # with the specs, so continue to use transaction strategy for speed.
    driver_shares_db_connection_with_specs = Capybara.current_driver == :rack_test

    unless driver_shares_db_connection_with_specs
      # Driver is probably for an external browser with an app
      # under test that does *not* share a database connection with the
      # specs, so use truncation strategy.
      DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
    end
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.append_after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

end
```

3) tal como lo indica el archivo database_cleaner.rb tengo que desactivar en spec/rails_helper.rb la siguiente linea poniendolo como false

```
config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
```

Finalmente en mi factoryBoot (factoryGirl antes)

puse el user {} para que no se repitiera

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
    user {Faker::Code.asin}
    name "Alex Fin"
    email 'alexf@supercat.com'
    password 'password'

    trait :super_usuario do
      roles :super_usuario 
    end

    trait :cliente do
      roles :cliente 
    end


  end
end
```